# Adding html configured in a function into an ExtJS 4 MVC

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I want to inject an old style, procedurally built string into a DIV element that's created in a standard ExtJS 4 MVC application, and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how I'm supposed to leverage dynamic loading.

So say I have this function by itself in a javascript file called "createHtml.js":

```
function fillDiv(strDivName)    {
    document.getElementById(strDivName).innerHTML = "<h1>TEST</h1>";
}
```

Elsewhere, in my MVC ExtJS 4 app (so *in an object referenced within app.js*, I have the following:

```
myPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Map',
    html: '<div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>'
});
```

In my index.html page, I include a reference to createHtml.js.  In my app.js file, I have something like the following:

```
( function() {
    Ext.Loader.setConfig({
        enabled : true,
        paths   : {
            MyJive: 'media/js/ext/MyCom/MyJive',
        }
    });
    Ext.onReady( function() {
        var urlparams = document.URL.split('?')[1];
        var param = Ext.urlDecode( urlparams ? urlparams : '' );
        var pcard = Ext.create( 'MyJive.view.MyUI',{
            param1 : param.param1,
            param2: param.param2
        });
        Ext.create( 'Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [pcard]
        });
    });
})();
```

Now if I attach a listener to a button somewhere on MyUI and have it call `fillDiv('map');` I get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: fillDiv is not defined` error.

If I put fillDiv not in its own file (createHtml.js) but MyUI.js (referenced by pcard, above), I'm golden.  So I know it's not a super-stupid issue like having the div id wrong or some wacky, invalid innerHTML value.

I would have thought the app would know about fillDiv() because fillDiv()'s parent file is in index.html's javascript includes, but fine, createHtml.js isn't being dynamically loaded.  I've got that, I guess.

But how do I tell app.js that my function exists in a file outside of its bounds?

(Now, "IRL", I've got fillDiv creating a complicated piece of html via [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) so that we can display a map identified by param1 and param2 embedded in the ExtJS form, but I've gone to this simpler setup to try and figure out what I'm doing wrong.)

**EDIT:**  Added index.html.  createHtml.js contains the `fillDiv()` method.  Note that the DIV that takes the map isn't in the index.html; it's, again, defined in an ExtJS Panel.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Project</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
                href="media/js/ext/ext-4.0/css/ext-all.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
                href="media/js/ext/MyCom/MyJive/css/main.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" 
                src="media/js/ext/MyCom/MyJive/createHtml.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" 
                src="media/js/ext/MyCom/MyJive/OpenLayers-2.11/OpenLayers.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" 
                src="media/js/ext/ext-4.0/ext-all-debug-w-comments.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript"
                src="media/js/ext/MyCom/MyJive/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="divParent"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** Adding app.js:

```
( function() {
    Ext.Loader.setConfig({
        enabled : true,
        paths   : {
            MyProj: 'media/js/ext/MyCom/MyProj',
            OpenLayers: 'media/js/ext/MyCom/MapJive/OpenLayers-2.11',
            MyComExt  : 'media/js/ext/MyCom/MyComExt'
        }
    });
    Ext.onReady( function() {
        var urlparams = document.URL.split('?')[1];
        var param = Ext.urlDecode( urlparams ? urlparams : '' );
        var pcard = Ext.create( 'MyProj.view.MyProj',{
            param1: param.p1,
            param2: param.p2
        });
        Ext.create( 'Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [pcard]
        });
    });
})();
```

Comment: Please share you index.html file with the reference to createHtml.js

Comment: @Macy Done.  Does that help at all?

Comment: You can see and call function in parent scope. Just I cant see where you call `fillDiv()` function. Also you can test if `console.log(window.fillDiv)` defined or not

Comment: app.js creates an object that creates a GUI.  Part of that UI creation is the fillDiv call.  If I call fillDiv from the included file, nothing.  If I call fillDiv2 (the same function that I put into the object file), it works.  I'll add the function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would leave just a comment, but I don't have enough points for that.

You didn't include a index.html file with imports of your createHtml.js and app.js files. But the first thing I would check is that your createHtml.js import is placed above app.js.

Comment: Looks like I'm okay there.  Was hoping for a second it was that stupid an issue.

Comment: You were on the right track. Long story short, the files were included incorrectly. [Excellent debug steps suggested here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?210792-Insert-HTML-into-Panel-s-DIV-via-innerHTML-MVC-amp-custom-funct&p=816084&viewfull=1#post816084) where I asked on sencha.com.

Comment: Yes, those are great debug steps, I use them all the time. First thing I try when something is not working correctly, log everything around it and that is enough to solve many problems.

Comment: Yeah, usually I'm smarter, but I let the ExtJS MVC Loader blind me to good, standard JS debugging and make me think it was much more complicated that it should've been.  Stupid.